# Center horizontal list style menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**CSS**

```
#main
{
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    border:solid 1px #efefef;
}

#links
{
    background-color:#808080;
}

#links ul
{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    height:30px;
}

#links ul li
{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="links">
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
            <li>Link 4</li>
            <li>Link 5</li>
            <li>Link 6</li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
</div>
```

The list items are dynamic so I can't really use fixed width on the #links layer and I want the list to be perfectly centered.  The above code doesn't work and I've a variety of methods but can't seem to get the list centered.

I don't want to use a table partly because I hate using tables for menus and also I will have eventually have sub menu items that will also be horizontal.

Any pointers?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the possible solutions:

- [Centre widthless floats](http://www.pmob.co.uk/pob/centred-float.htm)
- [Centering Float Left Menus](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
text-align:center;
```

To `#links`

`#links ul` sets the left and right margins to auto. Which will make them equal size if the container is told to center its contents. The line above will do that.

Comment: tried this before and unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

A little style detail to Safraz answer (thank you that worked for me too!)

When I set left:%50 of the ul, and left:-50% of the li items.
The browser shows a horizontal scrolling bar, though there's nothing to see (the scrollbar is there because of the overflow that is produced by the UL with left 50%), so the solution is to add to the wrapping div (in this case id=links) this style:

**CSS**

```
#links
{
    /* .... */
    overflow-x: hidden ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin 0 auto only works when you give a width!
you need to use inline block, then text align center

```
ul {
    text-align: center;        
}
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```